# get and insert textarea value into database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

My code is:

```
      @{
    var updatedabout= Request.Form["updateabout"];
        var db = Database.Open("database3");
if (isPost) {
        var update = db.QuerySingle("UPDATE users SET about = @0 WHERE [E-mail] = @1",updatedabout,WebSecurity.CurrentUserName); 
}}

<form class="horizontal" action="" method="POST">
    <textarea id="updateabout" name="updateabout" rows="5">example</textarea>
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

i wanted to submit what the user wrote in the text area to the database. but i cant get it to work. the code above is what i have so far.

Comment: ok what is not working?

Comment: it doesnt submit anything, the field in the database stays null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Request.Form["updateabout"]; gets value from query string but in your case you have a text area. If you are using javascript try to use 
var updatedabout=document.getElementById('updatedabout').value;
```

Comment: your exact code didnt work but i managed to get there with ur help, thanks brother